# Django 'int' object is not iterable when trying to update objects in views

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I am getting this error when trying to update objects from False to True. here is my code:

```
class ListNoti(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
      raise_exception = True
      model = Notifications
      template_name = 'notifications/notifications.html'
      
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          data = super(ListNoti,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
          data['noti'] = Notifications.objects.filter(receiver=self.request.user,is_seen=False).order_by('-date').update(is_seen=True)
          
          return data
```

`.update(is_seen=True)` raising this error `TypeError at /notification/ 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Move `update(is_seen=True)` before `order_by`

Comment: Ahtisham tried but didn't work

Comment: Check if it works without order_by

Comment: Ahtisham I tried both before posted the question. didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue after using queryset in my views. here is my full code:

```
class ListNoti(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

      raise_exception = True

      model = Notifications

      template_name = 'notifications/notifications.html'

      def get_queryset(self):

        data =   Notifications.objects.filter(receiver=self.request.user).update(is_seen=True)

        return data

     

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

          data = super(ListNoti,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

           

          data['noti'] = Notifications.objects.filter(receiver=self.request.user)

          return data
```